# sed capture to get string between slashes

Tags: shell, sed

I have a filepath like this: /bing/foo/bar/bin and I want to extract only the string between bing/ and the next slash.

So /bing/foo/bar/bin should just produce "foo".

I tried the following:

```
echo "/bing/foo/bar/bin" | sed -r 's/.*bing\/(.*)\/.*/\1/'
```

but this produces "foo/bar" instead of "foo".

Comment: Do you want to print `foo` a) because it follows `bing` in  the path or b) because it's the 2nd directory of the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

```
echo "/bing/foo/bar/bin" | sed -r 's|.*bing/([^/]*)/.*|\1|'
```

use `|` as delimiters instead of `/` is proper in your case, reference from "[Delimiters in sed substitution](https://coderwall.com/p/khdkuw/delimiters-in-sed-substitution)",

> sed can use any character as a delimiter, it will automatically use the character following the s as a delimiter.

or

```
echo "/bing/foo/bar/bin" | grep -oP "/bing/\K(\w+)"
```